# Remove iCloud Downloads from recovery terminal

Tags: macos, icloud

I am stuck with MacOS Big Sur, that tells me on startup that it needs to be reinstalled before booting, and only allows me to enter recovery to do so.

When trying to reinstall it, I get a message indicating that there is no sufficient disk space to do so. It turns out that most of the space is taken by local copies of iCloud folders for which I would like to delete the local copies in order to free up space to be able to proceed with the installation without data loss.

I cannot find a way to do so from the terminal, without `brctl`.

Where are these files stored, and how can I delete the local copy without causing it to delete the iCloud version when the computer next boots up?

Thanks